# Display all authors in cite bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

When I cite the reference I have only the first author and the year. I want to display all authors and year. What I must do ?

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
 colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = blue,
 linkcolor = blue,
 urlcolor=blue
 }
\begin{document}
\citealt{Li2001}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Li(2001)]{Li2001} Li W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2001) Clustering of highly    homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases. Bioinformatics  17(3):282-283
 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: How can LaTeX know the authors, if you don't tell it? The full list should go in the optional argument to `\bibitem`, but it's ***much*** better to have BibTeX do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you like doing it manually do this:

```
\bibitem[Li, Jaroszewsk and Godzik (2001)]{Li2001} Li W, Jaroszewsk L,........
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
 colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = blue,
 linkcolor = blue,
 urlcolor=blue
 }
\begin{document}
\citealt{Li2001}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Li, Jaroszewsk and Godzik (2001)]{Li2001} Li W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2001) Clustering of highly    homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases. Bioinformatics  17(3):282-283
 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

Now how about using the *beast* called `bibtex`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
 colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = blue,
 linkcolor = blue,
 urlcolor=blue
 }
 \usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @article{Li2001,
 Author =    {Li, W and Jaroszewsk, L and Godzik, A},
  Journal =  {Bioinformatics},
  Pages =    {282--283},
  Publisher =    {Springer},
  Title  =   {Clustering of highly    homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases},
  Volume =   17,
  number = {3},
  Year =     {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\citealt*{Li2001}
%\setlength{\bibhang}{2em} %% if you want to change the indentation in bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Only thing left is to choose a proper bibliography style. This has the advantages of flexibility of changing styles, re-usability of `.bib` databses etc.